# MiKTeX: Error Invalid argument Function: putc

Tags: errors, miktex

After recently having updated my MiKTeX installation I am unable to compile a large document written in german any more.

Luckily I was able to reduce the problematic document to the following 7 line MWE. The german text sequence has been shortened to the shortest possible length for the error still to occur. Therefore the incomplete german word `grunds` which was `grundsätzlich` in the original document.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
Während für die Phasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds
\end{document}
```

Compiling this MWE by `pdflatex MWE-utf8.tex` results in the following error message output on the command line:

```
[]\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 Whrend f
Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
```

The log file contains the following info regarding this compile run:

```
INFO  pdflatex - this process (10004) started by 'cmd' with command line: pdflatex MWE-utf8.tex
INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
FATAL pdflatex.core - Invalid argument
FATAL pdflatex.core - Function: putc
FATAL pdflatex.core - Result: 22
FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: <no data>
FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\c4pstart.cpp:285
FATAL pdflatex - Invalid argument
FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\c4pstart.cpp
FATAL pdflatex - Line: 285
INFO  pdflatex - this process (10004) finishes with exit code 1
WARN  miktex.core - still open: MWE-utf8.log
WARN  miktex.core - still open: MWE-utf8.aux
WARN  miktex.core - still open: MWE-utf8.tex
```

Here are my findings to the moment:

I have checked that the document and the MWE are indeed encoded in utf8. German umlaut `ä` is represented by byte sequence `c3 a4`, `ü` by `c3 bc` and `ö` by `c3 b6`.

The problem could be reproduced on two different machines running Win10 x64 and MiKTeX updated to a repository dated 2020-07-12. MiKTeX version info is `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.6.29)`. On the second machine MiKTeX was completely uninstalled and reinstalled from scratch.

The problem does not occur on a machine running Win10 x64 and MiKTeX updated to a repository dated 2020-06-15. MiKTeX version info is `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit)`

For the error to occur, the problematic german text sequence `Während für die Phasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds` has to be immediately at the beginning of a new paragraph. If any other text is placed at the beginning of a new paragraph in front of the problematic german text makes the error disappear.

Modifying the problematic text in some way makes the error disappear too. For example writing the - of course senseless - text `Während fürn die Phasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds` removes the error.

Error occurs for the following texts:

```
Während für die Phasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds
Während fürn ie Phasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds
Kährend für die Phasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds
Aäbcded für die Phasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds
Aäbcded güh ijk Lhasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds
```

No error in the following cases:

```
Während fürn die Phasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds
Während für die Phasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grund
Lährend für die Phasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds
Während fü die Phasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds
Während für die Phasenströme aufgrund de Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds
Aäbcdef für die Phasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds
Aäbcded güh ijk Lmasenströme aufgrund der Sternschaltung die Nullsystemfreiheit grunds
```

Writing any text behind the offending text sequence still gives the error message. For example completing `grunds` to `grundsätzlich`.

Changing the encoding of the document to ISO8859-1 and using `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` stil gives the error. Just for reference: `ä` is represented by `e4`, etc.

Replacing `\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrbook}` by `\documentclass{article}` removes the error message and the modified MWE compiles successfully.

Using `\documentclass{scrbook}` without the `[parskip=half-]` option also results in a successfull pdflatex run.

But of course I need the `scrbook` class in conjunction with the `[parskip=half-]` option for my final document.

Can anybody reproduce this error with the above mentioned MWE on a recently updated MiKTeX installation? Is there any way I can fix this error and get my document compiling again?

Comment: That is  this bug https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/581. It should be resolved soon, until then use e.g. \raggedright to avoid that the messages go to the terminal.

Comment: You can also call pdflatex with `--interaction=batchmode`, then nothing go to the terminal and the compilations succeeds.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the immediate solution.
```--interaction=batchmode``` works perfectly fine.

Just for my understanding: Why does the occurence of the error depend so heavily on the exact character sequence?

Comment: It matter what is written to the terminal: if you look in the log, you will find an overfull hbox message, with Umlauts: `Während für die Phasen-ströme auf-grund`. The umlauts are bytes and not allowed in utf8, but as miktex tries to write utf8 to the terminal it fails on the invalid bytes. Texlive avoids the problem by dropping the umlauts on the terminal:  Whrend fr die Phasen-strme auf-grund der Stern

Comment: I suggest to change the title to "MiKTeX: Error  Invalid argument Function: putc ". That makes it more specific.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.
Compilation also works from within TeXnicCenter without error.
I get the errors only when calling pdflatex from within a command prompt terminal.

Comment: Changed the title as proposed by Ulrike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update: the bug has been resolved.

---

This is a passing bug in miktex. It fails if some message should be written to the terminal which contains bytes which are invalid in utf8. In your case it is a overfull box message which contains Umlauts. The log-file (which is 8bit encoded) contains then this, and miktex is trying to write it to the terminal too:

```
Overfull \hbox (4.07864pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16--17
[]\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 Während für die Phasen-ströme auf-grund der Stern-schal-tun
g die Null-sys-tem-frei-heit grunds
```

TeXlive avoids the problem by dropping the Umlauts on the terminal:

```
Overfull \hbox (4.07864pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16--17
[]\T1/lmr/m/n/10.95 Whrend fr die Phasen-strme auf-grund der Stern-schal-tun
g die Null-sys-tem-frei-heit grunds
```

MiKTeX will do something similar soon too, see https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/581. Until then compile with
`--interaction=batchmode` to avoid terminal output.